# Can replacing wires fix a display

Tags: macbook-pro, display

I dropped my laptop on the ground.  For about 7 days the display would not work though the hard drive was fine.  I could use the computer with a different display.  The display has magically started working again but it has flickered off for a few seconds twice over a period of ten minutes.  Perhaps the only thing that is wrong is that some wires went ajar during the dropping and they just need to be replaced.   Can one purchase wires and easily replace them?  I have a Macbook Pro Retina Mid 2015.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can one purchase wires and easily replace them?

The “wires” is called a flex cable and it can be purchased.

Easily?  That depends on your level of technical skill.

Typically, wires don’t “go ajar;” connectors break.  You may have broken solder joints, a connector my be damaged connector on the logic board.  Without putting hands on, it is impossble to know what’s wrong.  At present all you have is symptoms:

- dropped MacBook
- Intermittent display

There’s a myriad of causes for those symptoms so until it’s opened up and properly diagnosed, everything is speculation.

Answer (score 2):

No, on the newer MBPs, the display cable is basically integral to the "Display Assembly" part, even if it is just the cable that was damaged it is not replaceable on its own, not "easily" by any reasonable standard.

Realistically if the display cable is seriously damaged you need to replace the entire display half of the laptop.

If it is only the display connector that is damaged, it may be possible to repair but the smt soldering needed for such a job means it would not be easy either, though you might be able to find a third party repair shop that could do it for you without replacing half the laptop.

Though I don't think it is likely, if the problem is that the display cable connector simply came loose, then that would be an easy fix. But I feel that would just be wishful thinking.